# Nothing but pairs of a kind

Tags: wordplay, river-crossing

**The objective is to reduce a given word to nothing in a series of steps.**

**At each step, remove every occurrence of an adjacent pair of letters of your choosing.**

**For example:**

- Problem:  Reduce CONCOCTION to nothing in three steps
- Solution:

  1. Step 1:  Remove every occurrence of "TI": `CONCOCTION` -> `CONCOCON`
  2. Step 2:  Remove every occurrence of "CO": `CONCOCON` -> `NN`
  3. Step 3:  Remove every occurrence of "NN": `NN` ->

**Please solve the three following problems in the given number of steps:**

1. Reduce ARCHITECTURE to nothing in four steps
2. Reduce HETEROJUNCTION to nothing in five steps
3. Reduce CHLOROFLUOROCARBON to nothing in six steps

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ARCHITECTURE:

> ARC**HI**TECTURE -> ARCTECTURE
>  AR**CT**E**CT**URE -> AREURE
>  A**RE**U**RE** -> AU
>  **AU** ->

HETEROJUNCTION:

> HETERO**JU**NCTION -> HETERONCTION
>  HETER**ON**CTI**ON** -> HETERCTI
>  HETE**RC**TI -> HETETI
>  H**ETET**I -> HI
>  **HI** ->

CHLOROFLUOROCARBON:

> CHLOROFLUORO**CA**RBON -> CHLOROFLUORORBON
>  CHL**OR**OFLU**OROR**BON -> CHLOFLUBON
>  CHLOFL**UB**ON -> CHLOFLON
>  CH**LO**F**LO**N -> CHFN
>  C**HF**N -> CN
>  **CN** ->

Answer (score 5):

I know this has already been answered, but I gave it a go without cheating so I want to answer too!

ARCHITECTURE:

> 1 - "HI" > ARCTECTURE
>  2 - "CT" > AREURE
>  3 - "RE" > AU
>  4 - "AU" >

HETEROJUNCTION:

> 1 - "JU" > HETERONCTION
>  2 - "ON" > HETERCTI
>  3 - "RC" > HETETI
>  4 - "ET" > HI
>  5 - "HI" >

CHLOROFLUOROCARBON:

> 1 - "CH" > LOROFLUOROCARBON
>  2 - "CA" > LOROFLUORORBON
>  3 - "OR" > LOFLUBON
>  4 - "UB" > LOFLON
>  5 - "LO" > FN
>  6 - "FN" >

Comment: Nice work!  And you revealed a little secret about the making of this puzzle.  I could only find a handful of words that had a single, unique solving path with the qualities that I wanted (CONCOCTION, ARCHITECTURE, ANTAGONISTIC, IMPLEMENTING, SPECTROSCOPY, and HETEROJUNCTION).  The word CHLOROFLUOROCARBON actually has seven different solving paths, all slight variations of each other.  You managed to find a different variation from the one that @juicifer presented!